# Excel: Copy contents of column one table to another table

Tags: excel

My question is for Excel 2013

I am trying to copy the contents of a dynamically generated table i.e. from a power query to another sheet where I create my own calculated columns and make a pivot table from that.

Here I have difficulties in copying the contents of the dynamically generated output of powerquery to another sheet.

I have tried the formula `=Table_name[@column_name]`, This does link the column, but the destination table is not adjusted according to the original table rows. The destination table rows seem to be fixed and do not change as the source table rows change when I refresh the power query connection.

Is there a simple easy way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score -2):

An Excel formula (by default) is executed every when you select a cell of the active sheet and click Send. All formulas of the sheet will be executed and values updated.
An excel formula update the value of the cell, is not itself the value!!!

To accomplish to your problem, and have an automatic update of your values you have to link the data, try [to read this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-21e995b5-bab1-4328-8ab3-dd357fe0e653).